# Different line spacing in rmarkdown main text and tables

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, kableextra, flextable

I am creating a pdf document with rmarkdown. I have tables created with `flextable` and `kableExtra`.

I have change the line spacing of my document by adding

```
---
linestretch: 1.5
---
```

to my YAML. this has successfully changed the line spacing throught my dicument. But I want to keep the line spacing in my tables to 1. Is there a way to specify line space defaults for tables created with kable and flextable?

Comment: You should post a complete example with a few lines of text and a short table (or a couple of short tables, one for `kableExtra`, one for `flextable`.

Comment: For me, using `kableExtra::kbl()` in place of `kable()` gets single spacing as long as I add a caption to the table.  I don't use `flextable`, so I can't help you there.